# how to insert two letters in string at all possible posions

Tags: python

for spell checker I want to add two missing letters in spelling.
Please suggest me how to do it in python.
I have code for adding one letter.

```
def splits(word):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(word) + 1):
        result.append((word[:i], word[i:]))
    print result
    return result

def inserts(word):
    result = []
    for a, b in splits(word):
        for c in alphabet:
            result.append(a + c + b)
    return result
```

for eg, I have word `He`

I want result `Haeb`, `aHeb`, `abHe` etc

Comment: Please include some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: I highly recommend studying this classic script: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def insertEach(chars, original):
  if not chars:
    yield original
  else:
    for doted in insertEach(chars[1:], original):
      for i in range(len(doted) + 1):
        yield doted[:i] + chars[0] + doted[i:]

[ x for x in insertEach('ab', 'HI') ]
```

results in:

```
['abHI', 'baHI', 'bHaI', 'bHIa', 'aHbI', 'HabI', 'HbaI', 'HbIa', 'aHIb', 'HaIb', 'HIab', 'HIba']
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP wants the original order of letters in the word to be preserved, i.e. he wants to put two letters in all possible positions in the word 'ab', but the order of 'a' and 'b' can't be changed.

Comment: The original in my example is `"HI"`, not `"ab"`.  `a` and `b` are the letters to be inserted.  Should I make that clearer in my answer?

Comment: I've looked at your code inattentively, thought that the word comes first, and the chars to be inserted are the second argument. I'd rather change the order of arguments, because it seems more native for me. anyway, +1 for working solution.

Comment: NP.  But I won't change them as that any reader can choose as he or she likes anyway.  I prefer this order because it fits my reading ("insert each (of) chars (into) original").  But I'm well aware that this is a subjective matter.